# Labeling elements of a table

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I have a table of the form(the table is very long, i put an example):

```
 tab1={{{1,10,30},{1,20,54},{1,30,65}},{{2,10,35},{2,20,65},{2,30,70}}}
```

How can I give index to elements of this table? I would like to have such a rule:

```
 tab1[x][y][z]
```

so that I can operate on its elements. For example, I would like to obtain,for every x:

```
 sum[x]=30+54+65  (*sum of z given x=1*)
```

And for every y:

```
 sum[y]=30+35    (*sum of z given y=10*)
```

Comment: `Total` with level specification?

Comment: I am not able to understand why `sum[x]=30+54+65` is `sum of z given x=1`? How did it know to sum only the third elements in the first list, and not say sum the second elements of the first list? And also `sum[y]=30+35` is `sum of z given y=10` how? Please try to explain more clearly how these were generated. If there are implicit assumption, then make them explicit. Any way, as was mentioned above, better to just use `Total` with the proper `Part` specifications. No need for all this gymnastics just to access parts of lists. Mathematica has good support to access any Part of lists. ? `[[ ]]`

Comment: These are given data, in a triplet form whose first, second and third elements are respectively x,y and z. All I want to do is ,for a given x, to sum z's for different y's and, for  a given y, sum z's for different x's.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) for the kind of slicing/dicing you wish to perform:

```
ds = Dataset[Join @@ MapIndexed[
     AssociationThread[{"class", "group", "x", "y", "z"}, Flatten[{#2, #}]] &, tab1, {2}]]
```

[image]

```
ds[GroupBy["x"], All, {"y", "z"}]
```

[image]

```
ds[GroupBy["y"] /* Map[Total], Select[#"x" == 1 &], {"z"}]
```

[image]

We can define a function that takes a predicate, a grouping key, a list of target keys and a function to be applied to the target keys:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[selector_, groupbykey_, keys_List, func_] := 
 ds[GroupBy[groupbykey] /* Map[func], Select[selector], keys]
```

***Examples:***

```
foo[#x == 1 &, "y", {"z"}, Total]
```

[image]

```
foo[True &, "y", {"z"}, List]
```

[image]

```
foo[True &, "y", {"z"}, Total]
```

[image]

```
foo[#z >= 35 &, "x", {"y", "group"}, Mean]
```

[image]

```
foo[#z >= 35 &, "x", {"y", "group"}, Identity]
```

[image]

```
foo[#z >= 35 &, "x", {"y", "group"}, bar]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> These are given data, in a triplet form whose first, second and third
>   elements are respectively x,y and z. All I want to do is ,for a given
>   x, to sum z's for different y's and, for a given y, sum z's for
>   different x's.

In that case, why do you care about having them as list of list of lists?  You could Flatten them at `1` and just do

```
sum[label_, value_, list_List] := Module[{r},

  (*assumes list has the form {{x,y,z},{x,y,z},...,{x,y,z}}*)

  r = Which[label == "x",
    Cases[list, {value, _, _}],
    label == "y",
    Cases[list, {_, value, _}],
    label == "z",
    Cases[list, {_, _, value}]
    ];
  Total[r[[All, 3]]]
  ];
```

Call it as

```
tab1 = {{{1, 10, 30}, {1, 20, 54}, {1, 30, 65}},
             {{2, 10, 35}, {2, 20, 65}, {2, 30, 70}}
          };
sum["x", 1, Flatten[tab1, 1]]
(* 149 *)

sum["y", 10, Flatten[tab1, 1]]
(* 65 *)

sum["y", 30, Flatten[tab1, 1]]
(*135*)
```

etc.. The function above is just to make it easier. Otherwise, you could just do

```
Total[Cases[Flatten[tab1, 1], {1, _, _}][[All, 3]]]
(* 149 *)

Total[Cases[Flatten[tab1, 1], {_, 10, _}][[All, 3]]]
(*65*)
```

etc...